# How to assign a variable to a button name and send that from one page to another page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have not worked with PHP for a long time. Recently, I have been assigned to a PHP project. I am in a like memory refreshing state now.

My problem is I have two PHP files.

1. test1.php
2. test2.php

**test1.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
    <?php
        $description = "desc";
        echo "<button name='.$description.' value='1'>description!</button>"
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST[$description]; //Undefined variable '$description'
echo $answer;

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM StatsData WHERE code_name=$answer";
?>
```

**Output**

```
Warning: Undefined variable $description
Warning: Undefined array key
```

The problem is, I cannot pass the variable which is in the name tag to test2.php. How can I achieve my result?

Comment: I'm not sure but can you try `$_POST['desc']` instead? Because `$description` has a value of `desc`, it will also be the name of the key in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: `$_POST['desc']` will definitely work. But, I cannot use it that way in my project

Comment: This kind of feels like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you explain what problem you're trying to solve with the above code, we might be able to come up with some better solution. Why do you need to use a variable instead of hard coded names with dynamic values?

Comment: You can put `$description` in another file then require it on both `test1.php` and `test2.php`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am trying to store `$answer` value in a SQL statement.I will update my code

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  I have confused between name tag and value tag. That was the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of adding a variable to the name tag and send it to another page and output the value. **But, I am wrong. It was all about the value tag**

**test1.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
    <?php
        $description = "1";
        echo "<button name='desc' value='$description'>description!</button>"
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST["desc"];
echo $answer;

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM StatsData WHERE code_name=$answer";
?>
```

---

With the help of this community, I found out what was my mistake. **I have confused between name tag and value tag. That was the reason.**

Comment: I found out what was my mistake. - First step to learning....

Comment: @Pupil Exactly. Time to follow some good tutorials :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is not the best one, I would rather define a hidden field in test1.php, which hold the name of button, then in test2.php get it and display the button value

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="btnName" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
    <?php
        $description = "desc";
        echo "<button name='.$description.' value='1'>description!</button>"
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in test2.php

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST[$_POST["btnName"]];
echo $answer;
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Maybe additional code will help.

Comment: In `<?php echo $description; ?>` , I got an error called `$description` is not defined

Comment: 1. In the form, you're echoing `$description` before you define it. 2. `echo "<button name='.$description.' value....` is not the correct syntax. It should be `echo "<button name='$description' value...` (without the dots) since you're in a double quoted string.

Comment: Hi @Kalana, you got the error because you use a var before it is define, try to move $description = "desc"; to the top of the file, before you use it